# Moving files from One Location to Another using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

using below code to transfer the files from one location to another location based on the files name.

But my my below code only popup the messahe that files successfully moved but in actual files do not move.

I hope someone can help m to fix the issue. Thanks.

[image]

```
 Sub MoveFilesFromExcel()

    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    Dim FilePattern As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileNotFound As Boolean

    ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation for performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Error handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in the worksheet
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' Start from row 2 (assuming row 1 contains headers)
    
        ' Get the source location, file pattern, and target location from columns A, B, and C
        SourceFolder = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        FilePattern = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        TargetFolder = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value

        ' Check if the source folder exists
        If Len(Dir(SourceFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            FileNotFound = True ' Set the flag to True if the source folder is not found
            GoTo CleanExit ' Exit the subroutine if the source folder is not found
        End If
        
        ' Loop through files in the source folder using the specified file pattern
        FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & "\" & FilePattern)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            ' Move the file to the target folder
            Name SourceFolder & "\" & FileName As TargetFolder & "\" & FileName
            FileName = Dir ' Get the next file
        Loop
        
    Next i

CleanExit:
    ' Show a message if any files were not found and exit the subroutine
    If FileNotFound Then
        MsgBox "Source folder not found.", vbCritical
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

    MsgBox "Files moved successfully!", vbInformation

ErrorHandler:
    ' Turn on screen updating and automatic calculation again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Even if you comment the code to move the file, you will still get the message box as it is just a statement which has nothing to do with the "file move" code. Put a breakpoint in the `Do While` code and check if the code execution is even entering the loop. Also show the message box only if the file has moved. You can do that in 2 ways. Use a boolean variable and set it to true inside the Do While loop or simply check if the file exists.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and for offering a solution. To be honest, if I were truly an expert, I would have certainly found a solution myself instead of posting here @Siddharth Rout

Comment: I can give you code in a platter but that will not help you in the long run :). If you do not know how to put a breakpoint, may I recommend watching [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZLuco1-klw&t=806s). After this, give it a try and then if you are still stuck, I will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: Apart from the aforementioned MsgBox displaying without a check if anything actually got moved, your code works as it should. Are you sure the pattern/foldernames are correct?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout sure and thanks

Comment: @Notus_Panda yeah everything is correct files names etc

Comment: Can you give an example of a row's A/B/C values that you know should contain files to move?

Comment: @Notus_Panda added a picture in the question

Comment: File pattern maybe not found in folder.

Comment: This is text file that i have saved with the same name as available in the workbook, sometimes files format is different like xlsx, xlsm, txt and dat.

Comment: Try `FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & "\" & FilePattern & "*")`

Comment: There is no extension for the file names, is it true?

Comment: @Notus_Panda worked thank you so much. Please post your answer.

Comment: @Black cat
 yes true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it'd be either the folder path or the filepattern that was the issue since I tested your code as-is on my end and moved a file.

On my end, I used `*.xls*` hence why I asked for an example. The image clearly shows a lack of extension of said files so VBA takes it literally, in your case:

`FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & "\" & FilePattern)`
would be looking for "C:\Users\Mg\Desktop\1926DI41" exactly without any extensions so you weren't getting in the loop as Siddharth thought.

So this does the trick:
`FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & "\" & FilePattern & "*")`